# combine my php code and a mysql statement in one sql statement

Tags: php

I have created a "suggested friends" php script, similar to facebook. My database has 2 tables, **users(user_id, name, surname, profile)** and **friends(friends_id, user_one, user_two)**. My code is the following:

```
<?php

//----- gets all friends of my friends -------

$friends_of_friends = mysql_query(" SELECT u.*
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_one as user_id
            FROM friends
            WHERE user_two IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
                         FROM friends
                     WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
                     UNION DISTINCT
                     SELECT user_two
                     FROM friends
                     WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
                       )
            UNION DISTINCT
            SELECT DISTINCT user_two
            FROM friends
            WHERE user_one IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
                     FROM friends
                     WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
                     UNION DISTINCT
                     SELECT user_two
                         FROM friends
                     WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
                       )
           ) f
          JOIN users u
          ON u.user_id = f.user_id  ");

while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_of_friends)) {
    $friend_friend_id = $run_friends['user_id'];


 // ---- gets friends of my friends that are not my friends -------------------------------

 $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two='$friend_friend_id') OR (user_one='$friend_friend_id' AND user_two='$session_user_id')   ");

   if (mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) != 1){ 

    $not_friends = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE (`user_id`='$friend_friend_id' AND `user_id`!='$session_user_id')  ");

       while ($run_not_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($not_friends)) {
         $not_friend_id = $run_not_friends['user_id'];
                 echo $not_friend_id;
       } //end while

   } //end if

} //end while

?>
```

My code works fine and gives me all friends of my friends that I want. Is it possible to combine all the above code in one spl statement? Any idea how to do this?

Comment: any idea how to write one mysql statement that will select friends of my friends?

Comment: *"Is it possible to combine all the above code in one spl statement?"* -- The answer is most likely yes, but looking at the nature of the queries, I think it will be incredibly slow to execute the query. At least a lot slower than doing it in a couple of queries.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. The reason that I was looking to do this in one mysql statement, is that would like to use LIMIT in order to get the first 4 friends of my friends. So write like :  $not_friends = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE (`user_id`='$friend_friend_id' AND `user_id`!='$session_user_id') LIMIT 4; ");  and it is not working. I have descovered that in order to use LIMIT there should be one main selection from a table. In my case after using I use many selections and if statement, making me unable to apply LIMIT.

Comment: I believe I saw a question from you earlier where you asked for the query above. The query seems awefully complex for what I think it returns. I can't remember if you gave the table layout for `users` and `friends` in that question. If you did, can you give the link to that question, or otherwise add the table layout (relevant fields only if they are very big) to this question?

Comment: I was trying to apply pagination for "friends of my friends", without any success. Maybe you mean this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915122/cannot-apply-pagination-successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems awefully complex for what you are trying to achieve. As far as I can tell the only fields that are relevant for your original query are `user_one` and `user_two` in `friends` and `user_id` in `users`. By using sub-queries, the runtime of the query will increase exponantially.

That would mean you could rewrite it to the following query, which should be a lot faster, because mysql can short-circuit out a lot of results instead of having to do every single sub-query. It returns all users that are friends from friends from a certain user I'll call 'x' from here on. Friends of 'x' that are not a friend of a friend are not returned and because of the AND at the end, it will not return the user itself either.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM friends as a, friends as b, users as c
WHERE (a.user_one = 1 AND (
  (a.user_two = b.user_one AND b.user_two = c.user_id) OR
  (a.user_two = b.user_two AND b.user_one = c.user_id)
  ) OR (a.user_two = 1 AND (
  (a.user_one = b.user_one AND b.user_two = c.user_id) OR
  (a.user_one = b.user_two AND b.user_one = c.user_id)
  )
 )) AND c.user_id != 1
ORDER BY c.`user_id` ASC
```

To remove all users that are direct friends from 'x' from the results you can use `NOT IN( ... )`. I use a sub-query for this, as I don't believe there is a way to do this without sub-queries. I could have joined an extra `friends` table, but even if I test if the current user is a friend from `c.user_id` against that newly joined table, the query could procceed by matching any of the other friends in that part of the query, which is something we don't want. The sub-queries will (or should) execute exactly once per unique friend-from-friend. I think the performance would be better if you had those queries seperate and compared both returned arrays with each other, but that would not allow you to use `LIMIT` in the query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM friends as a, friends as b, users as c
WHERE (a.user_one = 1 AND (
  (a.user_two = b.user_one AND b.user_two = c.user_id) OR
  (a.user_two = b.user_two AND b.user_one = c.user_id)
  ) OR (a.user_two = 1 AND (
  (a.user_one = b.user_one AND b.user_two = c.user_id) OR
  (a.user_one = b.user_two AND b.user_one = c.user_id)
  )
 )) AND c.user_id != 1 AND
 c.user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT friends.user_two FROM friends WHERE friends.user_one = 1 UNION
   SELECT friends.user_one FROM friends WHERE friends.user_two = 1
 )
ORDER BY c.`user_id` ASC
```

I believe this should link to the correct sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c14e/2

Comment: I changed my code above, have a look at it.Using your help, I found it. The only problem is that it displays in friends of friends and my user_id. Any idea to get to make it not displaying my id? Thanks....

Comment: All the 1's should be replaced with the user_id of whatever person you are using it for.